# How to debug typescript files in vs code when using webpack

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, vscode-debugger

I use typescript for nodejs server and I also use webpack and then output server.js file located in build folder not beside server.ts.
When I use server.js in launch.json, debugger works and ofcourse hits breakpoints in bundled server.js file. the configuration in launch.json like below:

```
"name": "Nodemon Launch Server",
"type": "node",
"request": "launch",
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/server/build",
"runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/server/build/server.js",
"console": "integratedTerminal",
"internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
"outFiles": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/server/build/*.js"
]
```

but I want to debug ts files and set breakpoint on typescript codes not js.
but when I change launch.json program as below:

```
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/server/server.ts",
```

it gives this error when I run the debugger:

> Cannot launch program '...' because corresponding JavaScript cannot be found.

How can I fix this to debug ts files not webpack bundled js file?

Answer (score 0):

The first one you should check is that the [source maps](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) has been generated. After that maybe you have to setup `outFiles` (e..g.:`"outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/path-to-my-compiled-files/**/*.js"]`).